# How to keep taking values from the user in C but stop when the user does not enter any value and presses enter?

Tags: c++

```
int k;
vector<int>v;
while ((scanf("%d", &k)) != EOF) {
    if (v.size() > 20) break;
    else {
        if (k > 0 && k <= 120) v.push_back(k);
    }
}
```

**The above snippet is taken from codechef blogs **

Comment: there is no language called C/C++. The code you posted is C++. Please only tag two languages when the question is about interoperation between the two

Comment: What is the issue? The code you posted seems to do what you ask for: https://godbolt.org/z/qzvvePzP9

Comment: I thought you might understand C/C++ is C language "OR" C++ language. Sorry for not being specific about it. However the code in the link :-  godbolt.org/z/qzvvePzP9 does not work in VS (Visual Studio) . Thanks

Comment: what is the meaning of "does not work" ? I didnt say that you have no issue, I just said that I cannot see the issue. Please explain in your question what problem you have

Comment: "" Enter age value (press ENTER without value to stop) "" This is what its given in the question however the while loop continues taking values instead of stopping

Comment: @spaghetticode Perhaps it'll be easier if you go with C++ instead of mixing in C style functions. Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/YqsjEexnY) with some nifty C++ classes. Read about them and look at examples at https://cppreference.com for the classes and functions you don't already know about.

Comment: Please add all relevant info to the question, you can [edit] it. The comments section isn't the right place. Also, you forgot to add the link to the source of the code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<rant>**Never tag a question both C and C++ on SO again**. It is reserved for questions about interoperations or very specific language-lawyer points, and should not be used for code that could be more or less used on both languages. In that latter case choose one in your first question and *if you later need it* ask a new question for the other language</rant>

Your problem is that for the `scanf` family questions spaces and newlines are just ignored when you use a `%d` conversion character. And `scanf` returns the number of elements that could be decoded and only stops on an end of file, read error or conversion error.

If you want to be able to detect an empty input, you will have to use `fgets` + `sscanf` from the C standard library, or `getline` + `stringstream` from the C++ one.